# Is passivation of stainless steel feasible in the field?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry

Does anyone have input or experience on passivation of stainless steel, particularly in outdoor environments where submersion of components is not practical due to location or size? Nitric acid (and solutions with sodium dichromate) typically call for submersion for extended periods of time based on the concentration of the solution. Citric acid has been referenced as a more suitable alternative and is more environmentally friendly but the literature on non-submersion passivation techniques is limited. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example? what do you mean by field, purpose etc.

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski  I am looking at the post-manufacturing passivation for AISI 301LN ¼ Hard and 1/2 Hard Stainless Steel sheets, specifically around areas where spot welding occurred.  The sheets are attached to framework with spot welding and were initially passivated, though not to an acceptable level, as rust is appearing after 1-2 months of normal outdoor exposure (no notable chemical exposures).  The passivation would need to be done outdoors and submersion is not an option due to the size of structure (up to 100' long).

Comment: That could be problematic, any solutions I am aware of require concentrated acids. They could be sprayed onto the surface and neutralise afterwards.